# университетская лаба по си

Tags: c

у меня университетская лаба по си, все вроде хорошо, быстро написал, но вот начал тестить и начались проблемы. Задача звучит так: для натурального числа К напечатать фразу "мы нашли К грибов в лесу", согласовав окончание слова "гриб" с числом К.
Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "locale.h"
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); // подключаем русский язык
    int k, t; 
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    t = k;
    k = k % 100; // получаем остаток от деления
    if (20 < k) { 
        k = k % 10;
    }
    if (k == 2 || k == 3 || k == 4) {
        printf("Мы нашли %d гриба\n", t);
    }
    if (k == 1) {
        printf("Мы нашли %d гриб\n", t);
    }
    else { printf("Мы нашли %d грибов\n", t); }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда пользователь к примеру вводит число 102, то выводится в консоль "Мы нашли 102 гриба" (что верно), и "Мы нашли 102 грибов" (что неверно). Естественно, это происходит из-за else, но я не понимаю как исправить, просто не понимаю! Помогите новичку пожалуйста. [image: Это пример со 101, мне кажется, что "else" не "срабатывает", потому что он стоит сразу после условия с k==1, но вот когда я ввожу 102 (см. след. картинку)]
[image: когда я ввожу 102 срабатывает "else" потому что он до условия с k==2 и т.д.]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что if-выражения не связаны между собой. Получается, что сначала отрабатывает код первого if:

```
    if (20 < k) { 
        k = k % 10;
    }
```

Затем второго куска кода:

```
    if (k == 2 || k == 3 || k == 4) {
        printf("Мы нашли %d гриба\n", t);
    }
```

А затем уже срабатывает этот код вместе (здесь else относится только к выражению k==1, то есть если оно неверно, то срабатывает код внутри else):

```
    if (k == 1){
        printf("Мы нашли %d гриб\n", t);
    }
    else { printf("Мы нашли %d грибов\n", t); }
```

Для того, чтобы решить проблему, почитай про else if. Например, это можно сделать тут: http://cppstudio.com/post/6449/?ysclid=l8dmf2tqwg278134678 (последний абзац пример кода с else if)